# Laravel Admin plugin, how to call a function only once for each row

Tags: laravel, optimization, grid-layout, laravel-admin

I have a Laravel project with Laravel admin running on it.
On the "Users" page I'm trying to display information both from the `users` table and the `pocket money` table like so:

```
...

use Encore\Admin\Controllers\AdminController;
use Encore\Admin\Grid;
use HerazikaServer\Models\User;
use HerazikaServer\Models\PocketMoney;

...

class UserController extends AdminController
{
    protected function grid()
    {
        $grid = new Grid(new User());
        // I'm trying to call this function only once for each row like so
        // $current = PocketMoney::getCurrentMonthDetails($grid->id);

        $grid->column('id', __('Id'));
        $grid->column('nickname', __('Nickname'));

        ...

        $grid->column('current pocket money period')->display(function() {
            $current = PocketMoney::getCurrentMonthDetails($this->id);
            return isset($current) ? $current->current_start_date.' '.$current->current_end_date : '';
        })->style('min-width:100px');
        $grid->column('daily objective')->display(function() {
            $current = PocketMoney::getCurrentMonthDetails($this->id);
            return isset($current) ? $current->daily_objective : '';
        });
        $grid->column('monthly objective')->display(function() {
            $current = PocketMoney::getCurrentMonthDetails($this->id);
            return isset($current) ? $current->monthly_objective : '';
        });
        $grid->column('attendance')->display(function() {
            $current = PocketMoney::getCurrentMonthDetails($this->id);
            return isset($current) ? $current->attendance.'/'.$current->monthly_objective : '';
        });
        
        ...

        return $grid;
    }
}
```

However I am having to call `$current = PocketMoney::getCurrentMonthDetails($this->id);` for every column (about 20 times total). Is there a way to call the function only once?
I tried something along the lines of `getCurrentMonthDetails($grid->id);`. but it obviously throws an undefined error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try these solutions:

1、where you start function ,you can try

```php
$items = PocketMoney::query()->where('...')->limit($page,$limit)->all()->keyBy('id');
//..usage
$grid->column('monthly objective')->display(function() use($items) {
            $current = $items[$this->id]
            return isset($current) ? $current->monthly_objective : '';
        });
```

2、where you call $grid->column(),you can try :

```php
function loadPocketMoney($id){
    if(!$item = cache()->get('product_'.$id)){
        $item = PocketMoney::getCurrentMonthDetails($id);
        cache()->set('product_'.$id,$item);
    }
    return $item;
}

$grid->column('monthly objective')->display(function() use($items) {
    $current = cache()->get('PocketMoney_id')?:loadPocketMoney($this->id)
    return isset($current) ? $current->monthly_objective : '';
});
```

Comment: I tried the first method first, then gave up because the ```->where('...')``` that I suppose is taken from ```PocketMoney::getCurrentMonthDetails($id)``` was quite intricated. So I tried the second and it worked! I will give another attempt to the first option later on.

Comment: I'm working with the second method for now, would the cache need to be unset at some point?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the code correctly, but shouldn't ```$current = cache()->get('PocketMoney_id')?:loadPocketMoney($this->id)``` be ```$current = loadPocketMoney($this->id);```?  Because you are already checking the cache inside the function. @gouki

Comment: sorry ,change
```php
$grid->column('monthly objective')->display(function()  {
    $current = loadPocketMoney($this->id)
    return isset($current) ? $current->monthly_objective : '';
});
```